# Can jQueryCycle show multiple images at once, but slide one at a time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to have 3+ images on a page with 3 images visible and be able to advance one image at a time. Something like this:

```
[Slide 1][Slide 2][Slide 3]
```

Then when the user clicks Next

```
[Slide 2][Slide 3][Slide 4]
```

Is it possible to do this with [jQueryCycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle)? If not, what jQuery plugin would you recommend for this?

This [example](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/div.html) shows 3 images, but it scrolls all 3 when clicking the nav buttons.

Comment: I implemented a similar solution with ul, li. Perhaps that will give you an idea. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/QScXU/6/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) is quite common for this sort of thing but I´m sure you can find other ones as well.

**UPDATE**

Created a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eCt6f/) that makes use of the `scroll` setting;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        wrap: 'circular',
        scroll: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: I've used jCarousel and I like it also.

Comment: Will it work like the example provided by SKS in the comment above?

Comment: Stefan: Yes its a circular carousel and yes its showing 3 images, BUT the important piece is that is only slides 1 image at a time when the buttons are clicked...this example doesn't do that. It does the same things that the example I provided does :s

Comment: @SomethingOn Use the configuration property "scroll" to set the number of items to scroll by. http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration

Answer (score 6):

According to @malsup himself, no :(

https://twitter.com/#!/malsup/status/162288824737734656

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Cycle 2 can do this; it's called the "carousel transition". A demo and documentation can be found on [Cycle 2 Carousel](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php). Note that you need to add the optional "Carousel" plugin available from the [Cycle 2 download page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/download/).